# How do I play FLV and MP4 files on my jailbroken iPhone 4, without converting the files?

Tags: iphone, mp4

I have a jailbroken iphone 4. Is there  way to play MP4 and FLV files without converting them? I'd like to play them straight on my iPhone,since it takes too spend time to use iTunes to convert the files.

Answer (score 1):

VLC (google it) plays just about everything. Unfortunately, due to a strict interpretation of some open source licenses (that is, not Apple's fault), the iOS version was pulled from the App Store.

Fortunately, though, you can still install it by using [Cydia](http://cydia.saurik.com/). Or at least that's what I've read (I haven't done it myself), see the [instructions](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2011/01/09/installing-vlc-player-from-cydia-a-video-walkthrough/) for details.

Getting the video files onto your phone will be more of a hassle, but I think this might be your best bet. Can't hurt to try.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the app GPlayer in the app store and see if it does what you need in regards to playing video. There's a free, ad-supported version and an ad-free version available.  No need to jailbreak.

Answer (score 0):

iPhone 4 supports MP4 files. Sometimes it is quite common that iPhone 4 cannot play MP4 files due to the codec issues. FLV is not a file format supported by iPhone 4. I am not sure if there is a quite nice solution to play MP4 and FLV files on iPhone 4 without converting them. I often convert the files to iPhone 4 supported formats. If you prefer, there is a quite nice way I know: http://software-iphonetools.blogspot.com/2011/10/how-to-play-flv-on-iphone-4s43gs3g.html

Answer (score -2):

there is a nice flash to video converter i usually use http://www.macvide.com/Macvide_FlashVideo_Converter/, i'd recommend it!) but thanx for info)

Comment: The OP specifically said "without converting the files"